# Transaction stuck as "pending" in the GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I sent a transaction a few hours ago but it's still `Pending` (as indicated by the `History` page of the GUI). How do I resolve this?

Comment: thank you dear,you re a God
its very helpfull for me

Comment: For me this was caused by a problem on my own daemon so check those logs too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, if you're using the CLI, see this Q&A:

[Transaction stuck as "pending" in monero-wallet-cli](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-monero-wallet-cli)

---

It's important to make sure you're running the latest version (`v0.18.1.0` at the time of writing). You can check the version # on the `Settings` page of the GUI (under `Debug info`). If you're not running `v0.18.1.2`, please upgrade first:

[How do I upgrade my software to the newest version?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7991/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-the-newest-version)

---

**The following assumes you're using a local node**

A transaction being stuck on `Pending` is typically caused by the local daemon being out of sync with the network. To verify that you're fully synced, perform the following steps:

**[1]** Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI.

**[2]** Go to the `Log` tab.

**[3]** Type `status` into the `command + enter (e.g. 'help' or 'status')` box.

**[4]** An output will be displayed that looks like:

```
Height: 1456425/1456425 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 290.20 MH/s, v6, up to date, x(out)+x(in) connections, uptime xd xh xm xs
```

**[5]** Now to verify that you're actually fully synced, compare the first number (of `Height:`) to the height displayed on a blockchain explorer like, for instance, [XMRchain](https://xmrchain.net). You're fully synced if your height matches the height displayed on a block explorer.

**[6]** If the GUI is stating that you're fully synced (100.0%), but your height doesn't match the height displayed on a block explorer (and is off by a large number), it is erroneously reporting that you're fully synced. This is, fortunately, easily resolved as follows. First, exit the GUI and make sure to stop the daemon as well. Second, restart the GUI + daemon. Third, use the `status` command to verify that it's now correctly displaying the top height.

---

Once you've verified that you're fully synced, we can resolve the issue as follows:

**[1]** Go to the `History` page of the GUI and copy your transaction hash / ID.

**[2]** Use multiple block explorers (for instance, [XMRchain](https://xmrchain.net), [MoneroBase](https://monerobase.com/blockexplorer/), or [MoneroBlocks](https://moneroblocks.info)) to confirm that your transaction isn't present in either the mempool or the blockchain.

**[3a]** If it's present in the mempool, simply wait until it gets mined.

**[3b]** If it's present in the blockchain (i.e. mined already), but is still stuck on `Pending`, perform the following steps. First, exit the GUI and make sure to stop the daemon as well. Second, restart the GUI + daemon. Lastly, let it run until it says `Connected` in the left bottom. This should resolve your issue.

**[4]** If it's not present in the blockchain, again go to the `History` page and copy the transaction hash / ID.

**[5]** Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI

**[6]** Click on the `Log` tab.

**[7]** Go to the `command + enter (e.g. 'help' or 'status')` box.

**[8]** Type `status` to again verify that you're fully synced.

**[9]** Type -> `relay_tx <txid>`

**[10]** As an example, let's say your transaction hash / ID is `4d0f32b7b1c371f1807f4bd6552362cc5b3d61b68b8f8407bb93193f9b1b0273` (randomly taken from the blockchain), you type -> `relay_tx 4d0f32b7b1c371f1807f4bd6552362cc5b3d61b68b8f8407bb93193f9b1b0273`

**[11]** Use one of the blockexplorers to check whether your transaction is in the mempool now (and thus will be mined soon).

---

If these steps don't work for you, try these:

**[1]** In the `command + enter (e.g. 'help' or 'status')` box on the `Settings` page, type -> `flush_txpool`

Note that it doesn't return an output.

**[2]** Exit the GUI.

**[3]** Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).

**[4]** Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`

**[5]** Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.

You should now be able to send a new transaction. However, it could be that the "old" transaction hash / ID is still on the `History` page. You can safely ignore this.

---

**The following assumes you're using a remote node**

It is quite unlikely that a remote node is out of sync with the network. However, if, for some reason, it is and you used it to send a transaction (which got subsequently stuck on `Pending`), perform these steps to resolve your issue:

**[1]** Go to the `Settings` page and make sure to use a different remote node than the one you were using. A list of remote nodes can be found here:

https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

**[2]** Exit the GUI.

**[3]** Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).

**[4]** Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`

**[5]** Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.

You should now be able to send a new transaction. However, it could be that the "old" transaction hash / ID is still on the `History` page. You can safely ignore this.

---

If you, after all these steps, still aren't able to send out a transaction, it'd be best to either open a new issue the [GUI repository](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues) or contact me on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1/).

Comment: THANK YOU! Not sure I would be so appreciative if it had not been the last option that saved my day, ALAS i'twas. Great write-up, very informative and helpful. Thanks again!