# How do I upgrade my software to the newest version?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, monerod

I've been running one of the following:

- CLI / GUI v0.14.X.X
- CLI / GUI v0.15.X.X

How do I update these to the newest version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, we encourage users to check the integrity of the binaries and verify that they were signed by Fluffypony's GPG key. A guide that walks you through this process can be found [here](https://src.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/verification-windows-beginner.html) for Windows and [here](https://src.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/verification-allos-advanced.html) for Linux and Mac OS X.

**CLI:** (most recent version: v0.17.1.9)

If you are using the CLI you ought to perform the following steps:

1. Download the new binaries (the `.zip` file (Windows) or the `tar.bz2` file (Mac OS X and Linux)) from [the official website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) or [Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.17.1.9).
2. Extract the new binaries to a new directory of your liking.
3. Copy over the wallet files from the old directory (the one that contains the v0.15.X.X, v0.16.X.X, or v0.17.X.X binaries).

Note that a blockchain resync is not needed. Thus, if you open `monerod-v.0.17.1.3`, it will simply pick up where it left off.

---

**GUI:** (most recent version: v0.17.1.9)

If you are using the GUI you ought to perform the following steps:

1. Download the new binaries (the `.zip` file (Windows) or the `tar.bz2` file (Mac OS X and Linux)) from [the official website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) or [Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/releases/tag/v0.17.1.9).
2. Extract the new binaries to a new directory of your liking. This is the easiest and recommended way. Alternatively, however, you can overwrite the old binaries.
3. Open `monero-wallet-gui`¹. It should automatically load your "old" wallet and you should be set for the upcoming scheduled network upgrade.
4. If you're running a local node, the integrated daemon (monerod) will first have to convert your database to a new version. This may take a 5-10 minutes and the GUI will show that it's `Disconnected`. I'd advise to simply let it run and after the database conversion has completed the GUI will connect back to the daemon (monerod).

(1) On Linux you ought to start the GUI with the `start-gui.sh` script, i.e., `./start-gui.sh`.

(2) If, for some reason, the GUI doesn't automatically load your old wallet, you can open it as follows:

**[1]** On the second page of the wizard (first page is language selection) choose `Open a wallet from file`

**[2]** Now select your initial / original wallet. Note that, by default, the wallet files are located in `Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` (Windows), `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` (Mac OS X), or `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` (Linux).

Lastly, note that a blockchain resync is **not** needed, i.e., it will simply pick up where it left off.

Comment: Here is a script that might be useful: [upgrade-monero.sh](https://github.com/jonathancross/jc-docs/blob/master/upgrade-monero.sh)

Comment: I don't know you I can do it on the Macbook maybe im stupid but help would be nice :D

Comment: @user10911 - Do you still require assistance?