# I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui

I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain. How do I resolve this issue and let the CLI / GUI show my proper balance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, you have to ensure that you properly upgraded to v0.14. A guide can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7991/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-the-newest-version). In addition, your blockchain has to be "corrected" such that your node syncs to the right chain. A guide can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-13-to-cli-or-gui-v0-14-and-as-a-result). Thereafter, follow these steps:

## Local node

**GUI:**

1. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI.
2. Press on the `Log` tab.
3. In the `command + enter (e.g. 'help' or 'status')` box type -> `flush_txpool`
4. If you're unable to execute this command, proceed with step 7.
5. Your transaction should now show as `Failed` on the `History` page.
6. Your balance should now reflect the proper balance.
7. If not, exit the GUI, but keep the daemon running.
8. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).
9. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`.
10. Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.
11. You should see your proper balance once the wallet is fully refreshed.

---

**CLI**

1. Type `flush_txpool` into `monerod`
2. Use `show_transfers` (in `monero-wallet-cli`) to verify that your transaction now shows as `failed`
3. Your balance should now reflect the proper balance.
4. If not, type `rescan_spent` in `monero-wallet-cli`

---

## Remote node

It's quite unlikely that the remote node you connect(ed) to was running a v0.13 daemon (monerod), as most remote node lookups have proper checks in place. However, use the following steps if it occurred and you created / performed a transaction:

**GUI:**

1. Exit the GUI.
2. Browse to the directory your wallet files are located (`Documents\Monero\<wallet-name>` on Windows | `home/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` on Linux | `Users/<username>/Monero/<wallet-name>` Mac OS X).
3. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`.
4. Restart the GUI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.
5. You should see your proper balance once the wallet is fully refreshed.

---

**CLI:**

1. Exit the CLI.
2. Note that, by default, the CLI stores the wallet files in the same directory as `monero-wallet-cli`
3. Rename `<wallet-name>` (the file without extension) to `<wallet-name>-old`.
4. Restart the CLI. This will trigger a *wallet* refresh from scratch, which shouldn't take longer than 30 minutes.
5. You should see your proper balance once the wallet is fully refreshed.

Comment: "Type flush_txpool in the command box (you may need to highlight it with your mouse to see it, as we've gotten reports of it being fairly invisible)." Even after highlighting with mouse I can't see a command box?

Comment: Please see this Github issue for pointers -> https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1278

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Settings page of the GUI.

Press Show status <= There is no show status

A window should pop up.

Type flush_txpool in the command box (you may need to highlight it with your mouse to see it, as we've gotten reports of it being fairly invisible).

Your transaction should now show as Failed on the History page.

Comment: There is, see (10) of -> https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#6-settings. It probably has a different name if you are using a local language.