# Help! - 1.5 XMR Bounty

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, mymonero

[IMGUR ALBUM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y68K.jpg)

Hi - I'm in need of some help. If through someone's help I can recover this XMR, then 1.5 XMR will be given as a thank you! The case:

1. In Jan 2019 I sent XMR from the Monero GUI to a Kraken trading account. The transaction was initially stated as successful but stayed as "PENDING" on the GUI. Note: The GUI had not been updated since early 2018, so it was outdated and did not have bulletproof support, etc.
2. After a couple of days, the funds were still PENDING and hadn't appeared in Kraken. I downloaded the current GUI at the time and imported the old wallet, but the Daemon refused to start.
3. I deleted both the old GUI (which I still had installed) and the current one in an attempt to start over.
4. Today, in May 2019, I downloaded the current Boron Butterfly GUI, imported the wallet, but got a different Daemon error. I also downloaded MyMonero, where the balance also showed 0.0 and no evidence of a prior transaction. When I run monerod.exe from the Contents of the GUI I get several errors. Also - the payment ID and transaction # exist and were created when I initially sent the funds to Kraken, but they do not appear on the Monero Block Explorer.

Any help that leads to recovery of the funds would be appreciated and rewarded with 1.5 XMR!

Comment: Please just follow this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-13-to-cli-or-gui-v0-14-and-created-pe

Comment: Check that your firewall is letting monerod through. The firewall thinks that the new version software is completely different from the old version software and it has to be told to let the new software through the firewall manually. It also treats the GUI and Monerod as completely different software so each has to be let through separetely. Then check your antivirus software for the same reason.