# I lost all my funds after performing a transaction on the wrong (old) chain

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

Firstly I am assuming the responsibility for this loss, it was my mistake and if I cannot get back my coins, that is something I will have to deal with myself. I won't blame anyone other than me.

Back in 2018 I purchased some Monero and stored it in my Windows GUI Wallet (v0.11.1.0) using a local node and kept it in a spare computer I that I only use for crypto.

A few days ago (precisely on the 16th of may 2021) I logged in my Windows GUI Wallet (v0.11.1.0) and performed a transaction moving all my funds to a new address. The transaction did not finish successfully as I couldn't find it in any Monero blockchain explorers.

I did some research online and I found someone who had a similar issue. I followed all the steps on this link here:

[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-13-to-cli-or-gui-v0-14-and-created-pe)

I noticed that the transaction status has changed to Failed, but the funds have never returned and my balance is still zero.

I tried different approaches to solve this issue, with different Wallet Versions. In the first attempt I performed a database conversion that took more than 24 hours to finish. Then I tried remote nodes and also accessing the wallet by the CLI, but nothing worked.

This is what I see using the CLI:

```
[wallet 48doH9]: balance
Currently selected account: [0] Primary account
Tag: (No tag assigned)
Balance: 0.000000000000, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000
[wallet 48doH9]: rescan_spent
[wallet 48doH9]: show_transfers
  failed    out        -       2021-05-16 21:35:53       3.168872840000 8bab9614f5aa07f69481c5d01dff3fc111d01c3f1a33f5eb8e788041bafc8eff 0000000000000000 0.006060080000 48fGK9GYBrPSTMt23FUYMuZXuv7K37GrCi4ss7Um8RopVU4yPDt8CppPvkvyCDDapCQApnqPHyY1P3PcayBuq7wvEhoFYJL:3.168872840000  -
[wallet 48doH9]: balance
Currently selected account: [0] Primary account
Tag: (No tag assigned)
Balance: 0.000000000000, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000
```

Is there any hope or is it too late?

Comment: Try restoring your seed on a mobile wallet (Cake or monerujo). See if the balance shows up.  If so, make a new wallet on PC and xfer it there if you don't want to keep it on the mobile wallet.

Comment: I have managed to recover my coins!! Thank you all for the support! Amazing community we have here!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you have not lost your XMR I think.

Why not start with the latest version of GUI/CLI and restore your old wallet with your seed.

The coins should be in your old wallet. Also check the restore hight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where can I see the height information?

Answer (score 0):

Coins don't live in your wallet, they live on the blockchain.

Thus if you send a transaction to the wrong chain, nothing is lost; just update your software (GUI or CLI), sync the correct chain and rescan.