# Monero old version wallet wipeout my xmr

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I opened my wallet in gui 0.15.0.2, then files amnesia.old_cache and amnesia.unportable was made and my wallet was wipeout. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Please update to GUI v0.17.1.9: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7991/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-the-newest-version

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old version. Remove the wallet (except the .keys file, which you must keep), get a recent version, run that, and let it rescan the chain.