# Transaction stuck pending

Tags: transaction-confirmation

I have a few transactions that are stuck in the pending status (for about 2 days now).
My unlocked balance is near 0, so I cannot transfer any XMR. How can I solve these stuck transactions? What is the reason?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which version of the wallet are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-the-gui

Comment: Are you using a local or remote daemon?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve these stuck transactions?

If you have a transaction stuck at the daemon, you can flush it with `flush_txpool`:

```
$ monerod help flush_txpool
Command usage: 
  flush_txpool [<txid>]

Command description: 
  Flush a transaction from the tx pool by its <txid>, or the whole tx pool.
```

Then in your wallet you can `rescan_spent`.

> What is the reason?

If your domain is not in sync with the rest of the network or is on an incorrect chain, this kind of thing can happen.

Comment: flush_txpool "Pool successfully flushed"
rescan_spent
show_transfers
and still transaction is pending, new one transaction, older are failed. Can I be sure that this pending transaction will not be sent twice if I reply?

Comment: And still no ulocked Monero in wallet.

Comment: Can you see any of your pending txs by searching on https://xmrchain.net/ ?

Comment: I've made flush again, closed daemon, run again and all transactions are failed, seems problem solved.

Comment: Going to mark this as solved then @gdfhsd33