# Transactions keep failing

Tags: transaction-confirmation, transaction-failed

Using Monero GUI, I am attempting to make a transaction to an address who are requesting a specific amount, no more & no less. I have attempted sending it with their required amount, and their amount + the transaction fee thinking it may be required to be added on top.  I can't find out any reason why this wont be working, I have the funds and the address exists

[image]

Comment: Can you try with GUI v0.17.1.3? https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/jqmi8t/cli_gui_v01713_oxygen_orion_released/ | Note that an updated Linux binary will be released within 24 hours.

Comment: Additionally, please see: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/jrh7mv/psa_informational_thread_on_the_recently_observed/

Comment: Please also see the guide I linked. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-the-gui