# "Could not send the money. Status:Failed. Reason:double spend, invalid input"

Tags: transaction-failed

I am using  GUI 18.1.2.
A few weeks ago, I got 2-3 extra Monero in my wallet (without doing anything).
The day I saw it I successfully performed a transaction.

Now, a few days ago, my transaction did no get any confirmations and after having the status "sent(pending)" went into the status "send(failed)".
I therefore followed all the steps here (and some similar instructions) and also tried a remote node: [Transaction stuck as "pending" in the GUI](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-the-gui)

Now I cannot even submit a transaction but I am stuck with the error:

> Could not send the money. Status:Failed. Reason:double spend, invalid input

Do have any suggestions on how to get back in sync and also drop the wrongfully obtained Monero?

Comment: Solved by restoring from seed

Comment: To add, another way to resolve the issue is to change the node.